# Posting Audio (byte array) to MVC.NET Web Api

Tags: c#, android, asp.net-mvc, audio, asp.net-web-api

## The Problem

I am trying to send audio recorded by my android device to a MVC.NET Web Api.  I confirmed the connection by passing simple string parameters.  However, when I try to pass the byte array generated from the audio, I get a 500 from the server every time.  I have tried multiple configurations, but here's what I currently have:

## MVC Web API

```
public class PostParms
{
    public string AudioSource { get; set; }
    public string ExtraInfo { get; set; }
}

public class MediaController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public string Post([FromBody]PostParms parms)
    {
        byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(parms.AudioSource);
        return "success";
    }
}
```

## Android Code

```
public class WebServiceTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Long>
{   
    @Override
    protected Long doInBackground(String... parms)
    {
        long totalsize = 0;
        String filepath = parms[0];
        byte[] fileByte = convertAudioFileToByte(new File(filepath));        

        //Tried base64 below with Convert.FromBase64 on the C# side
        //String bytesstring = Base64.encodeToString(fileByte, Base64.DEFAULT);

        String bytesstring = "";
        try 
        {
            String t = new String(fileByte,"UTF-8");
    bytesstring = t;
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1)
        {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {
            url = new URL("http://my.webservice.com:8185/api/media");

            //setup for connection
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept","application/json");
            urlConnection.connect();

            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            json.put("AudioSource", bytesstring);
            json.put("ExtraInfo", "none");

            DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
            output.writeBytes(URLEncoder.encode(json.toString(),"UTF-8"));
            output.flush();
            output.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        return totalsize;
    }

    protected void onPreExecute(){

    }
    protected void onPostExecute(){

    }
    private byte[] convertAudioFileToByte(File file) {
        byte[] bFile = new byte[(int) file.length()];

        try {
            // convert file into array of bytes
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            fileInputStream.read(bFile);
            fileInputStream.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bFile;
    }
}
```

I can get a .NET application to work with the same API sending an audio stream, but not Android.  Like I said, I've tried a number of configurations found on the internet with encoding and the output stream, but continue to get 500.  I need help, as I am at a loss.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

I used a `ByteArrayEntity` instead of a `StringEntity`.

```
// ByteArrayEntity 

HttpPost request = new HttpPost(getString(R.string.server_url) + "SendMessage");
ByteArrayEntity be = new ByteArrayEntity(msg);
be.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
request.setEntity(be);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
```

On the server side, I used this web API code to get the byte array:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<string> SendMessage()
{
    byte[] arrBytes = await Request.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
    return "";
}
```

Comment: Worked For Me Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

I just posted a question on Stack Overflow at [Uploading/Downloading Byte Arrays with AngularJS and ASP.NET Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26005687/uploading-downloading-byte-arrays-with-angularjs-and-asp-net-web-api) that is relevant (in part) to your question here. You might want to read that post to set the context for my response. It is about sending and receiving byte[]’s via Web API. I have one issue with the approach, but it has to do with the JavaScript client incorrectly handling the server response.

I would make the following changes to your Server-Side code as follows:

```
public class PostParms
{
    public string ExtraInfo { get; set; }
}

public class MediaController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]// byte[] is sent in body and parms sent in url
    public string Post([FromBody] byte[] audioSource, PostParms parms)
    {
        byte[] bytes = audioSource;
        return "success";
    }
}
```

Read the post at http://byterot.blogspot.com/2012/04/aspnet-web-api-series-part-5.html

Use/add Byte Rot’s asynchronous version of the Media Formatter for byte[]’s.

I had to tweak the formatter as shown below for a newer version of ASP.NET.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Formatting;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace YOUR_NAMESPACE
{
public class BinaryMediaTypeFormatter : MediaTypeFormatter
{
    /****************** Asynchronous Version ************************/

    private static Type _supportedType = typeof(byte[]);
    private bool _isAsync = true;
    public BinaryMediaTypeFormatter() : this(false){
    }
    public BinaryMediaTypeFormatter(bool isAsync) {
        SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream"));
        IsAsync = isAsync;
    }
    public bool IsAsync {
        get { return _isAsync; }
        set { _isAsync = value; }
    }
    public override bool CanReadType(Type type){
        return type == _supportedType;
    }
    public override bool CanWriteType(Type type){
        return type == _supportedType;
    }
    public override Task<object> ReadFromStreamAsync(Type type, Stream stream,
        HttpContent contentHeaders, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger){// Changed to HttpContent
        Task<object> readTask = GetReadTask(stream);
        if (_isAsync){
            readTask.Start();
        }
        else{
            readTask.RunSynchronously();
        }
        return readTask;
    }
    private Task<object> GetReadTask(Stream stream){
        return new Task<object>(() =>{
            var ms = new MemoryStream();
            stream.CopyTo(ms);
            return ms.ToArray();
        });
    }
    private Task GetWriteTask(Stream stream, byte[] data){
        return new Task(() => {
            var ms = new MemoryStream(data);
            ms.CopyTo(stream);
        });
    }
    public override Task WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, object value, Stream stream,
        HttpContent contentHeaders, TransportContext transportContext){ // Changed to HttpContent
        if (value == null)
            value = new byte[0];
        Task writeTask = GetWriteTask(stream, (byte[])value);
        if (_isAsync){
            writeTask.Start();
        }
        else{
            writeTask.RunSynchronously();
        }
        return writeTask;
    }
}
}
```

I also had to add the following line to the config file.

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
     // This line added to activate your binary formatter.
        config.Formatters.Add(new BinaryMediaTypeFormatter());
```

/*********************************** Client-Code *************************************/

You will need to use 'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream' on the client.

You can send the byte[] as binary, but it has been too long since I have coded in C# on the client.

I think that the line: output.writeBytes(URLEncoder.encode(json.toString(),"UTF-8")); will have to be changed as a minimum.

I will have a look and see if I can find some C# client code snippets that might be relevant.

**Edit You might have a look at the C# client code of the following post. It may help you to tweak your code to work with the approach that I suggested.**

[How to Get byte array properly from an Web Api Method in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23884182/how-to-get-byte-array-properly-from-an-web-api-method-in-c)