# How to Get byte array properly from an Web Api Method in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have the following controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("SomeRoute")]
public byte[] MyMethod([FromBody] string ID)
{
  byte[] mybytearray = db.getmybytearray(ID);//working fine,returning proper result.
  return mybytearray;
}
```

Now in the calling method(thats also another WebApi method!) I have written like this:

```
private HttpClient client = new HttpClient ();
private HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage ();
byte[] mybytearray = null;
response = client.GetAsync(string.Format("api/ABC/MyMethod/{0}", ID)).Result;
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    mybytearray = response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;//Here is the problem
}
```

Now, the problem is the byte array `MyMethod` is sending is of 528 bytes, but here after making `ReadAsByteArrayAsync`, the size becomes larger(706 bytes) and the values are also goofed up.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

<strike>HTTP is a text based protocol</strike>. **edit**: HTTP can transport raw bytes as well. Luaan's answer is better.

The returned byte array will be converted into text in some way, depending on how the `MediaTypeFormatterCollection` is set up on the server and on the format requested by the HTTP client with the `Accept` header. The bytes will typically be converted to text by [base64-encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). The response may also be packaged further into JSON or XML, but the ratio of the expected length (528) to the actual length (706) seems to indicate a simple base64 string.

On the client side, you are not looking at the original bytes but at the bytes of this text representation. I would try reading the data as a string with `ReadAsStringAsync` and inspect it to see what format it is in. Also look at the headers of the response.

You should then parse this text accordingly to get the original bytes, e.g. with [Convert.FromBase64String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Getting this exception: The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.

Comment: Thank you very much.I just had to remove the "\" from the beginning, and it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 95):

Actually, HTTP can handle "raw" binary as well - the protocol itself is text based, but the payload can be binary (see all those files you download from the internet using HTTP).

There is a way to do this in WebApi - you just have to use `StreamContent` or `ByteArrayContent` as the content, so it does involve some manual work:

```
public HttpResponseMessage ReturnBytes(byte[] bytes)
{
  HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
  result.Content = new ByteArrayContent(bytes);
  result.Content.Headers.ContentType = 
      new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

  return result;
}
```

It may be possible to do the same thing using some attribute or something, but I don't know how.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42862627/httpresponsemessage-not-returning-bytearraycontent-asp-net-core which is related.

Answer (score 25):

`response.Content.ReadAsAsync<byte[]>().Result //Put this code in your client.`

I want to make it clear that `ReadAsAsync<byte[]>()` and `ReadAsByteArrayAsync()` do **NOT** act the same.

ReadAsByteArrayAsync() turns everything **into** a Base64 Byte Array. It doesn't get the non-Base64 `byte[]` from response.Content but `ReadAsAsync<byte[]>()` does

Comment: or: response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result

Comment: +1 First I tried with ReadAsByteArrayAsync() at first and it didn't work then I followed your answer to use ReadAsAsync<byte[]>() and worked for me.

Comment: located in nuget Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client

Answer (score 9):

Instead of this

```
mybytearray = response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;//Here is the problem
```

Use this

```
string result=null;
result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result.Replace("\"", string.Empty);
 mybytearray=Convert.FromBase64String(result);
```

response was returning the byte array as base64encoded.

Comment: Why does the result of `.ReadAsStringAsync()` wrap the desired string in `" "` ?

Answer (score 6):

Change your controller with this and you'll get the same size that you send

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("SomeRoute")]
public FileStreamResult MyMethod([FromBody] string ID)
{
  byte[] mybytearray = db.getmybytearray(ID);
  return File(new MemoryStream(mybytearray), "application/octet-stream");
}
```

This is an issue https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/7926

Answer (score 1):

This is my approach its worked for me

WEP API Method

```
            [HttpGet]
            [Route("pdfReport")]
            public byte[] ReportMRWiseCurrentStatus()
            {
    
                byte[] resultsarray = _materialRequestReportService.ReportMRWiseCurrentStatus();
                return resultsarray;
            }
```

The Client

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var response = client.GetAsync(webApiUrl);
                if (response.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {

                    var result = response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result.Replace("\"", string.Empty);

                    var bytearray=Convert.FromBase64String(result);
                    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\DB\newpdfAmila.pdf", bytearray);
                }

             }
```

Answer (score 0):

**From WEBAPI/Server end, pass the values like :**

```
String base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);     //Convert to ToBase64String
```

**and receive the values from client**

```
response = client.GetAsync("URL/home/GetFIle?id=" + File_id).Result;

responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

mybytearray = Convert.FromBase64String(responseBody);    //Convert to FromBase64String
```