# Display Byte Array Image in AngualrJS HTML from Web API Service

Tags: c#, html, angularjs, image, arrays

I'm building an AngularJS Application, for Service I'm using .NET C# for coding purpose. Now I'm following the Code Structure as mentioned in the following Post [Load image from C# Byte array and place image in html tag using AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35582748/load-image-from-c-sharp-byte-array-and-place-image-in-html-tag-using-angularjs) -

But in the said approach they are sending the Image as a Base64 Sting and here we are binding the Base64 in Angular HTML. It degrades the performance of loading. In one of my post I got an relevant answer [Compress a Byte Array Image without Scaling using .Net C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38627940/compress-a-byte-array-image-without-scaling-using-net-c-sharp), it stated "Send the data usual instead of Base64" string.

Kindly assist me how to display a Byte Array Image in **HTML `<img />` Tag**. Currently I'm using the following

```
<img ng-src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{ image.Content }}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Call binary image data through a controller function like this (as a possible solution, please see the link to Fiddle).

```
<img data-ng-src="{{getImage(image.Content)}}" />

$scope.getImage = function(data){
    return 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + data;
}
```

Have a look at the fiddle showing 2 possible approaches.
[JSFiddle as example](https://jsfiddle.net/mqh65ath/3/)

Comment: Here you are using one property `data`, its a Base64 String ?

Comment: Actually it's just wrapping the `data`object with the correct `data:image/jpeg;base64,` prefix. About your problem i notice you use image.Content - be aware that JS is case sensitive.

Comment: Here the `image.Content` is a `Base64 String` - `Convert.ToBase64String(imgArr)` - Here the problem is I'm returning string to the Client and then I'm binding the Sting  `image.Content` in the `<img ng-src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{ image.Content }}" />`. So, it degrades the performance. Now I'm sending the Byte array **`imgArr`** instead of  `Convert.ToBase64String(imgArr)`.