# Not able to return FileStreamResult asp.net core web API

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am writing HttpPost method and using FromBody attribute to send parameters.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult TransformData([FromBody]IList<Employee> argument)
    {
      //logic - output stream is built here 
      return File(output, MediaTypeNames.Application.Xml, "output.xml");
    }
```

From console application , I am trying to consume web API :

```
   ObjectContent data = new ObjectContent(args.GetType(), args, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
   using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://service:8080/");
            MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue contentType = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(contentType);

            var response = client.PostAsync("api/controller", data);
            response.Wait();
            var responseContent = await response.Result.Content.ReadAsAsync<FileStreamResult>();
        }
```

responseContent is null. Please help.

Comment: You have to retrun a filestream:                Stream stream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open);
                return File(stream, "application/pdf", $"Order.pdf");

Comment: output which i am using is of type System.IO.MemoryStream...

Answer (score 1):

```
var net = new System.Net.WebClient();
var data = net.DownloadData(link);
var content = new System.IO.MemoryStream(data);
```

you save the content to your computer

Comment: i referred this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49822132/c-sharp-httpresponsemessage-content-does-not-return-memorystream-correctly-to-ht