# No conversion from text to arraybuffer when using Ajax to get binary array from web api

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-core-webapi, binary-data

I am trying to receive binary array from web api from ajax client,

In my Api Controller I have:

```
[ HttpGet ]
[ Route( "Connection/ImageData" ) ]
public byte[] GetImageData()
{
    return new byte[1];
}
```

In my JavaScript I have:

```
function RenderImage() {
    try {

        $.ajax({
            url: "/Connection/ImageData",
            dataType: "arraybuffer",
            success: function(response) {                  
               //success!
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
               //api error;
            }
        });
    } catch (err) {
        //calling error
    }
}
```

I get the error:

```
No conversion from text to arraybuffer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The returned byte array will be converted into text in some way,
>   depending on how the MediaTypeFormatterCollection is set up on the
>   server and on the format requested by the HTTP client with the Accept
>   header. The bytes will typically be converted to text by
>   base64-encoding. The response may also be packaged further into JSON
>   or XML, but the ratio of the expected length (528) to the actual
>   length (706) seems to indicate a simple base64 string.

Reference :https://stackoverflow.com/a/23884624/10201850

Try the following code :

Controller

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("Connection/ImageData")]
    public string GetImageData()
    {
        var bytes = new byte[3] { 0,12,246 };
        var data = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
        return data;
    }
```

Javascript : using `base64ToArrayBuffer` function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function base64ToArrayBuffer(base64) {
        var binaryString = window.atob(base64);
        var binaryLen = binaryString.length;
        var bytes = new Uint8Array(binaryLen);
        for (var i = 0; i < binaryLen; i++) {
            var ascii = binaryString.charCodeAt(i);
            bytes[i] = ascii;
        }
        return bytes;
    }
    $("#btnclick").click(function () {
        try {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Connection/ImageData",
                //dataType: "arraybuffer",
                success: function (response) {
                   var result= base64ToArrayBuffer(response);
                    console.log(result);
                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log(errorThrown);
                    //api error;
                }
            });
        } catch (err) {
            //calling error
        }

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I do want to actually return a byte array without converting it to base64. I know you can do this using websockets. But usefulful code so +1.