# .NET Core HttpClient upload byte array gives unsupported media type error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to upload a simple byte array for my Web Api controller (ASP.NET Core 3)

```
using var client = new HttpClient() { BaseAddress = new Uri("http://someUrl.com/") };
var body = new ByteArrayContent(new byte[] {1, 2, 3});

var result = await client.PostAsync("api/somecontroller/content?someField=someData", body);
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost("content")]
public IActionResult Upload([FromBody]byte[] documentData, [FromQuery] string someField)
{
    ...

    return Ok();
}
```

but this gives me the error `415 Unsupported media type`. Why ? I need to put some additional data in the url, but I don't think that's the issue here.

Comment: Try this : on receiving side, remove body parameter and use stream on request body : `MemoryStream stream =new MemoryStream((int)Request.Body.Length);
await Request.Body.CopyToAsync(stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.ToArray(); `

Comment: Also, you could try to set the content header like in this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/23884972/479251

Answer (score 20, accepted):

While `byte[]` would be a great way to represent `application/octet-stream` data, this is not the case by default in asp.net core Web API.

Here is a simple workaround:

Send request by HttpClient:

```
using var client = new HttpClient() { BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:62033") };
var body = new ByteArrayContent(new byte[] { 1, 2, 3 });
body.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/octet-stream");           
var result = await client.PostAsync("api/Values/content?someField=someData", body);
```

Receive action in Web Api project:

```
[HttpPost("content")]
public IActionResult Upload([FromBody]byte[] documentData, [FromQuery] string someField)
{
        return Ok();
}
```

Custom InputFormatter in Web Api Project:

```
public class ByteArrayInputFormatter : InputFormatter
{
    public ByteArrayInputFormatter()
    {
        SupportedMediaTypes.Add(Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/octet-stream"));
    }

    protected override bool CanReadType(Type type)
    {
        return type == typeof(byte[]);
    }

    public override Task<InputFormatterResult> ReadRequestBodyAsync(InputFormatterContext context)
    {
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        await context.HttpContext.Request.Body.CopyToAsync(stream);
        return InputFormatterResult.SuccessAsync(stream.ToArray());
    }
}
```

Startup.cs in Web Api Project:

```
services.AddControllers(options=> 
        options.InputFormatters.Add(new ByteArrayInputFormatter()));
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Can you please async/await the ReadRequestBodyAsync method? I thought of some issues in my code and wasted 20 mins because of this.

Comment: pay attention that the "Request.Body.CopyToAsync" is not awaited, so every time it runs you could get a different part of the input stream! better use the async on the function and await the copyasync..

Comment: One of the methods seems to have a couple of typos.  It should be        public async override Task<InputFormatterResult> ReadRequestBodyAsync(InputFormatterContext context)
        {
            var stream = new MemoryStream();
            await context.HttpContext.Request.Body.CopyToAsync(stream);
            return await InputFormatterResult.SuccessAsync(stream.ToArray());
        }

Answer (score 2):

The issue is caused by the [FromBody] attribute which supports only simple types. You can use [Type Converters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api#type-converters) for other types. The correct controller action code should be:

```
    [HttpPost("content")]
    public IActionResult content([FromQuery] string someField)
    {
        var documentData= new byte[Request.ContentLength.Value];
         Request.Body.ReadAsync(documentData);
        //...
        return Ok();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Be aware that the answer above has typos, which may cost you quite a lot of time (code in the gif file is incorrect and may produce damaged not complete byte arrays):

```
public async override Task<InputFormatterResult> ReadRequestBodyAsync(InputFormatterContext context)
    {
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        await context.HttpContext.Request.Body.CopyToAsync(stream);
        return InputFormatterResult.Success(stream.ToArray());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [excellent answer from @Rena](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62422784/3370431) you can also use the following class to read the request body as a `Stream` parameter:

```cs
public class StreamInputFormatter: InputFormatter
{
  public StreamInputFormatter()
    => SupportedMediaTypes.Add(MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/octet-stream"));

  protected override bool CanReadType(Type ArgType) => ArgType == typeof(Stream);

  public override Task<InputFormatterResult> ReadRequestBodyAsync(InputFormatterContext ArgContext)
    => InputFormatterResult.SuccessAsync(ArgContext.HttpContext.Request.Body);
}
```

Your API controller action can then look something like this:

```cs
  [HttpPost]
  [Consumes("application/octet-stream")]
  public async Task<ActionResult> UploadData([FromBody] Stream ArgData) {}
```

When you do the above and use Swagger UI via the `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore` package, it will correctly show a file-input control which allows you to upload the binary data:

[image]