# Minimal Api byte[] parameter binding problem

Tags: c#, minimal-apis

If pass a byte array as parameter to a minimal api endpoint, like :

```
app.MapGet("api/srv/myget", [FromQuery] byte[] data) => DoSomethingWith(data);
```

then when I try to run it throws an exception with:

> No public static bool byte[].TryParse(string, out byte[]) method found
> for data.

For me is mandatory to keep the webservice's input format.
Is there a way to do this with minimal API?

Comment: What it looks like in a plain text format? `https://host/api/srv/myget/......`  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23884182/how-to-get-byte-array-properly-from-an-web-api-method-in-c

Comment: When you say you need to keep the input form, are you referring to the HTTP request or to the method signature? If it's the former, you can replace data with HttpContext and access data with context.Request.Query["data"].

Comment: When you specify FromQuery, you always end up in RequestDelegateFactory.BindParameterFromValue without a way to inject custom binders. The only known way for BindParametersFromValue to convert from a string is the static TryParse method. Static excludes extension methods. The fact we are talking about an array means we can't subclass.

Comment: Have you resolved this problem now?

Comment: This is not supported but its unclear what you are trying to do from the question above.